# When do browsers send referrers? How to prevent this?

Tags: html, security, web

As we all know, certain (most) browsers do send a [referrer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) alongside HTTP requests.

**When do browsers send referrers?**

Am I right that browsers **typically send a referrer** in both of these cases:

- User clicks a link, which loads new content in the **current** windows/tab
- User clicks a link, which loads new content in a **new** windows/tab [target="_blank"]

How about **JavaScript initiated request**, which replace the current DOM's location?

How about **AJAX-requests**? Do browsers send referrers even on **asynchronous requests**?

To effectively **prevent the forwarding of a referrer**, I may use a local or remote **link-forwarding service**.

**Eliminate referrers using HTML 5**

**HTML 5** provides a no `referrer` attribute/value described [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#link-type-noreferrer).

Do **current browsers respect** this or a similar attribute/value? Do current browsers even respect this attribute/value if the **current HTML page isn't marked** as HTML 5?

**Security**

Should **sensible parts of a site** always link foreign sites through a site-local link-forwarding service?

Sure, this would be 'security by obscurity'. Nevertheless, such a forward wouldn't cost much anyway..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on browser configuration.

This answer is about Firefox 27. Other browsers may behave differently

---

You can change the configuration setting `network.http.sendRefererHeader` in `about:config` to

- `0`: Never send the Referer header or set `document.referrer`.
- `1`: Send the Referer header when clicking on a link, and set `document.referrer` for the following page.
- `2`: Send the Referer header when clicking on a link or loading an image, and set `document.referrer` for the following page. (Default)

(See [MozillaZine article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.sendRefererHeader))

> Browsers typically send a referrer (..) user clicks a link

Yes, if `network.http.sendRefererHeader` is `2` or `1`. If it's `0`, no.

> How about JavaScript initiated request, which replace the current
>   DOM's location?

No, when changing `location.href` it isn't send.

> How about AJAX-requests? Do browsers send referrers even on
>   asynchronous requests?

Yes, both on synchronous and asynchronous send it if `network.http.sendRefererHeader` is `2`. If it's `1` or `0`, no.

> HTML 5 provides a `noreferrer` attribute

It is currently unimplemented, see [Bug 530396](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=530396).

Comment: Also, if you want even more fine-grained control over when and what referrers are sent Firefox has [several add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=referrer) that allow you to setup rules controlling it.